# Regex to get filename / exclude certain characters from the match

Tags: ruby, regex, io

Here's my file:

```
name.extension
```

And here's my regex:

```
.*[.]
```

However this matches the filename and the period:

```
#=> "filename."
```

How can I exclude the period in order to achieve:

```
#=> "filename"
```

I'm using Ruby.

Comment: What if your filename itself has period in it?

Comment: Filenames can't have periods though...all programs including windows explorer and osx Finder disallow it, so I don't think it's a problem. I may be wrong though, if you have a more robust solution I'd love to hear it

Comment: Well, I just created a filename with a period in it. Where did you saw that you can't have periods in filename?

Comment: @Starkers: `.`s are valid filename characters in many operating systems, including OS X.

Comment: Fair enough! Just realised. js.min and the like. Ah embarrassing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [***`File`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html) class methods [***`File#basename`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-basename) and [***`File#extname`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-extname):

```
file= "ruby.rb"
File.basename(file,File.extname(file))
# => "ruby"
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a negated character clas:

```
^[^.]*
```

This will match everything, from the beginning of the string till it finds a period (but not include it).

Comment: Almost, but that matches everything but the period. This matches everything preceding but not including the period: ^[^.]*

Comment: @Starkers. I didn't get your comment.

Comment: @Starkers. Yes, I realised that, and already edited the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Match upto the last "."

```
 "filen.ame.extension"[/.*(?=\.)/]
  # => filen.ame
```

Match upto first "."

```
 "filen.ame.extension"[/.*?(?=\.)/]
 # => filen
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create subgroups in the regexp and just select the first:

```
str = 'name.extension'
p str[/(.*)[.]/,1] #=> name
```